# How to prevent footnotes from causing text to be moved onto the next page in Word

Tags: microsoft-word

I have block paragraph of text in word which includes a footnote reference. The paragraph itself would fit on the end of a page, however there would be no space for the footnote. Because Word is not able to fit the footnote in, it instead moves the block of text [i.e. text and footnote] to the next page, leaving a big block of space at the end of that particular page.

While i understand why it is doing this (i.e. to avoid having a footnote reference included on one page, but the footnote itself on the next page), is there any way of overriding this setting - to have text on one page, and footnote on the next?

Comment: Have you changed the size of the margins in `page properties`? I'm not 100% sure, but I took a class on it once, and I remember it was linked to that.

Comment: @Dooley_labs by deceasing the margins I can force the text & footnote onto one page, but i don't really want to have smaller margins [i really want to get it so that the text comes on one page and the footnote on the next, rather than force them both onto the next page]

Comment: Then perhaps a page-break or try to put text in-between the footnote and the paragraph? It's been awhile since I've had to to play with footnotes, but that should be able to do it.

Answer (score 3):

If the footnote is shunting the entire paragraph onto the next page, then it is almost certainly because the paragraph is formatted with `Keep lines together`, which can be found on the `Line and Page Breaks` page of the `Paragraph` dialog. Turn this off and Word will flow the paragraph from one page to the next.

If that isn't the problem, then it must be that the footnote reference and the footnote cannot both physically fit on the same page because the footnote reference is too close to the bottom of the page. MS Word is able to flow a footnote from one page to another if the footnote consists of several lines, so you need only space for a single line of the footnote on the same page as the reference. So Word will never leave more than a few lines of space at the bottom of the page.

Answer (score 0):

This happened to me.  In my case, the text was in a table that had a minimum height.  The table was below some text, and the footnote would have forced the whole table to move to the next page, so instead Word chose to continue the table on the next page to avoid violating the minimum height.